# mysql get highest value with column name

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `myTable` like this:

```
Name    type1    type2    type3
----------------------------------------
John    3        6        9
Craig   5        2        24
```

I want to get whichever column has the highest for 'John'- that is, the column name, and the amount.

I can't think of a solution to handle it, any pointers?

Comment: Consider amending the table design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the query below to find highest value column using name:

```
SELECT Name, @highest_val:= GREATEST(type1, type2, type3) AS highest_col_value,
   CASE @highest_val WHEN type1 THEN 'type1'
                     WHEN type2 THEN 'type2'
                     WHEN type3 THEN 'type3'                         
   END AS highest_value_column_name
FROM myTable
WHERE Name = 'John';
```

If you want to retrieve all records then use the query below:

```
SELECT Name, @highest_val:= GREATEST(type1, type2, type3) AS highest_col_value,
   CASE @highest_val WHEN type1 THEN 'type1'
                     WHEN type2 THEN 'type2'
                     WHEN type3 THEN 'type3'                         
   END AS highest_value_column_name
FROM myTable;
```

Here [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) MySql function finds greatest value for given columns as **`highest_col_value`** and [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) will match with each column to find the column name as **`highest_value_column_name`**.

Comment: You need to be careful how to handle value ties though - if several columns jointly share the highest value you need to have a rule to decide which you want to pick which will depends on the case in point.

Answer (score 0):

There's no function that returns the column name based on some condition, but you can use the IF function. To get the largest value from a list, use the GREATEST function.

```
SELECT
    `Name`,
    IF(`type1` > `type2` AND `type1` > `type3`,'type1',
        IF(`type2` > `type1` AND `type2` > `type3`,'type2',
            IF(`type3` > `type1` AND `type3` > `type2`,'type3','N/A'
            )
        )
    ) as `maxColName`,
    GREATEST(`type1`,`type2`,`type3`) as `maxValue`
FROM `myTaable`
```

Comment: Oh dear, this feels like a step in the wrong direction

Comment: @Strawberry, No doubt. The data should be normalized.